# Frege: how are functions defined in concept script?

Tags: logic, math-history

Does anyone have an example of defining a functions both untyped and typed arguments using concept script?  Defining functions with single, multiple arguments and varying arguments?  My background is CS and perhaps guidance on a simple function like OR or NAND would be helpful.

I had a theory that a function was an inference string and its arguments the first inference.  To get the value of a function, one would deduct the argument.  For instance $\phi \implies (B \implies (A))$ and invoking $\phi(B) \equiv A$.  For multiple arguments $\phi \implies ((C \land D) \implies (A))$.  Perhaps my thinking's there is incorrect.

Any guidance appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The *ontology* of Frege's logic is : there are *objects* and there are *functions*.

Objects are "argument" of functions but not vice-versa.

The *concept-script* has symbols for both, that means that functions in [Frege's *Begriffsschrift*](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA23) are expressed through function symbols; see §10 :

> $\Phi(A)$ and $\Psi(A,B)$.

Some further examples from §23-on, withe the **General Theory of Sequences**.

See also [Frege's Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/#FreLogMat) :

> It is important to mention here that the predicate calculus formulable in Frege's logic is a ‘second-order’ predicate calculus. This means it allows quantification over functions as well as quantification over objects; i.e., statements of the form ‘Every function ƒ is such that …’ and ‘Some function ƒ is such that …’ are allowed. Thus, the statement ‘objects a and b fall under the same concepts’ would be written as follows in Frege' notation:
>
> > $(\mathfrak f) \mathfrak fa \equiv \mathfrak f b$
>
> and in the modern second-order predicate calculus, we write this as:
>
> > $∀F(Fa ≡ Fb)$.

---

See also the complete English translation of [Frege's *Grundgesetze der Arithmetik* (1893/1903)](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZxcbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA9) with the "specifications" for the language.

---

Very useful : Gregory Landini, [Frege’s Notations : What They Are and How They Mean (Palgrave, 2012)](https://books.google.it/books?id=kDZQvy6-9rwC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @Nick - sorry, I can't understand. Deduction is performed through Modus Ponens, and I cannot see in §6 specific use of parentheses...

Comment: I updated the post.  I'm appreciate any guidance you may have.  I'm basically trying to understand how to develop what Lambda calculus provides programming in concept script.  I.e. so I can write program flow that way.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nick - from the syntactical point of view, the concept-script is only High-Order Logic.

Comment: so does that mean it has no mechanism to define a function and it's arguments it accepts?  Thanks